# Use method to create a new object C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, lambda, asp.net-web-api2

[I have edited my POST then please recheck it]

I'm creating a ASP.NET MVC WEB API. Then with this code, I have to reuse code "new Child{...}" for many times. And I am stuck in searching for solutions. Please tell me the way to use a method of creating a new object in that lamba expression. Thanks very much

```
public IEnumerable<Child> GetChildren()
    {
        return db.Children.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new Child { 
            Address = x.Address,
            ClassId = x.ClassId,
            DietId = x.DietId,
            Dob = x.Dob,
            FirstName = x.FirstName,
            Gender = x.Gender,
            Id = x.Id,
            LastName = x.LastName,
            ParentName = x.ParentName,
            ParentPhoneNumber = x.ParentPhoneNumber,
            TakingCareId = x.TakingCareId,
        });
    }

// GET: api/Children/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Child))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetChild(int id)
    {
        Child child = db.Children.Find(id);
        if (child == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        } else
        {
            Child c = db.Children.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Id == id).Select(x => new Child {
                Address = x.Address,
                ClassId = x.ClassId,
                DietId = x.DietId,
                Dob = x.Dob,
                FirstName = x.FirstName,
                Gender = x.Gender,
                Id = x.Id,
                LastName = x.LastName,
                ParentName = x.ParentName,
                ParentPhoneNumber = x.ParentPhoneNumber,
                TakingCareId = x.TakingCareId,
            }).FirstOrDefault();
            return Ok(c);
        }
        //return Ok(child);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I presume you're querying data via the Entity Framework?  If so, you have two options that I commonly use in our apps:

1. Build the object through a constructor

   ```
   db.Children.Select(x => new ChildDTO(x));
   ```

The one downside of this approach is you will always query all of the fields in your database.  Sometimes this doesn't matter, sometimes it does.  It depends on your app and the data you're storing.

2. Create a reusable expression

   ```
   public static Expression<Func<Child, ChildDTO>> DefaultColumns {
       get {
           return c => new ChildDTO() {
               Id = c.Id,
               Address = c.Address,
               ...
           };
       }
   }

   db.Children.Select(DefaultColumns);
   ```

The advantage of this approach is you can query only the columns you need.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Entity Framework, let me try. Thanks. It sounds reasonably.

Comment: I have editted the post, please recheck it. I use your second way, and have change the code. "<Child, ChildDTO>" to <Child, Child>". And receive this error
 'IEnumerable<Child>' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Select<Child, Child>(IQueryable<Child>, Expression<Func<Child, Child>>)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable<Child>'

Comment: I found the problem with "AsEnumerable()". But if I remove it, the error "The entity or complex type 'Kindergarten_DBModel.Child' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query." occured again. hmmm.

Comment: What version of EF are you using?

Comment: And also, why do you need to project into a new object?  Is there a column you're specifically avoiding?

Comment: I'm  using the latest version of EF (6.x), Database-first. The model files generated have some keyword such as "partial class", "virtual class". It seems to be complex type to application to return XML / Json objects by directly parse dbSet. I dont want to delete those keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Using a method is fine, though you need to make sure to remember updating at when you add a new variable you want your DTO object to have.
So make sure it is in the correct class, preferablly in the Child class. Using a constructor is also good idea but it is not always what you want.
Also, you may want to take a look at Auto Mapper to map DTO objects more reliably.

Comment: I understand that. I just consider how to reuse the code to create a new object in the expression.